# In Full Metal Panic, what does Mithril do with the Whispered they rescue?

Tags: full-metal-panic

In the first episode of the first season, we see a Whispered woman being taken away from a Russian facility. Mithril turns up and secures the area before Sousuke injects a sedative into her and takes her away.

We know that Teletha "*Tessa*" Testarossa is a Whispered and works as the Captain of the Tuatha De Danaan while Chidori is relatively left to her own life (under protection).

What does Mithril do with the Whispered that they rescue? Are they put to work like Tessa, or are they relocated and kept safe in the same way Chidori is (i.e., allowed to live a normal life, but monitored)?

Comment: I have a feeling both Tessa and Kaname are special cases anyways.  They were going to pack up and stop watching Kaname after destroying the Russian lab (didn't they only _start_ actively monitoring her because they suspected she was being targeted?).  And Tessa clearly likes her job, and the relationships she has with her subordinates, so she's not likely being coerced (although I don't know how she got the job in the first place).  Probably, they leave most of them where they are, and may not actively monitor them, although I haven't read the light novels, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Whispered woman you are referring to is Mira Kudan, whom Sousuke rescued in Khabarovsk. She is the only Whispered 'captured' by Mithril of whom we are given any details about her subsequent life. In the light novel series, she at first works in Mithril's engineering division, and helps to build the Arbalest for Sousuke, to thank him for saving her. Later, she is relocated to a secret safehouse where she, presumably, lives out a normal life in peace and calm.

In the final novel, *"Always, Stand by Me: Part 2"*, she and Sousuke are in contact with each other over the internet, and before his final battle she emails him a copy of a video his classmates uploaded wishing him and Kaname a safe return to school. She appears happy and at peace, though still suffers residual trauma from her experiences.

I presume that other rescued Whispered are treated the same way: they can assist Mithril with their skills if they wish, or be put into protective custody where they can live quietly far from any of this.

Answer (score 0):

[Bani Morauta](https://fullmetalpanic.fandom.com/wiki/Bani_Morauta) is another Whispered that worked with Mithril. He developed the AI system 'AL' for ARX-7 Arbalest. According to his wiki page, he committed suicide right before the completion of ARX-7 Arbalest. He tried too hard to increase his Whispered ability by diving into resonance. He lost his mind at the end.